# access one subdomain from another

Tags: php, html, path, include, directory

I'm trying to access a javascript file that sits on a subdomain through a page that is a subdomain of the first subdomain. That is, I have a page at `admin.www2.mysite.com` that I'd like to have access to scripts in the `www2` subdomain (`<SCRIPT SRC="www2.mysite.com/resources/scripts/javascript/file.js"></SCRIPT>`)

Even hardcoding the link in like this doesn't work. I still get a 404. Even though looking at the `src` attribute in the head of the document seems right

`<SCRIPT SRC="www2.mysite.com/resources/scripts/javascript/file.js" TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT"></SCRIPT>`

Directly below it there is the error:

```
GET http://admin.www2.mysite.com/add_user/www2.mysite.com/resources/scripts/javascript/file.js
  directory within admin ------> ^^^^^^^^
```

I have tried to get at it by using , but `<SCRIPT SRC="<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/resources/scripts/javascript/file.js`

gives me the error:

`GET http://admin.www2.mysite.com/cyrious_add_user/admin.www2.mysite.com/resources/scripts/javascript/file.js 404 (Not Found)`

The directory `admin` is physically inside the directory `www2` on the server.

How can I navigate from this sub-sub domain to the other subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're omitting the scheme from the URL which causes it to be a relative path (hence the first error).  Simply add a scheme:

```
src="//www2.mysite.com..."
```

The `//` will use the same scheme as the page request.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks! Do you have any more information on these schemes?

Comment: @thomas don't forget to upvote/accept.  They're also called (incorrectly) "protocols," but in the context of the URI string it's "Scheme."  99% of the time probably either `http://` or `https://`

Comment: gotcha. sometimes I check back half-hour or so later because the system won't let me check the solution immediately. but I missed giving you your upvote, sry!